# Why Chart.js v2 time based data not aligning with X axis correctly?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When displaying time based data using Chart.js, the data itself doesn't seem to be aligned with the X axis labels. For instance, when the data is for 2016-11-30, the bar is actually showing in December. The last date in a series of dates doesn't even show on the chart. How can I make them align correctly?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var config = {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: [
        '2016-11-30', // Why showing in December?
        '2017-04-01', // Why not showing in beginning of April?
        '2017-06-30'], // Why not showing?
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Contacts',
                backgroundColor: 'red',
                data: [
          1,
          5,
          7
        ]
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero:true,
                        stepSize:1
                    }
                }],
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    barThickness:2,
                    time: {
                        unit: 'month'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    };

    var Canvas = $("#Chart");
    var cc = new Chart(Canvas, config);

});
```

Example on Codepen:
https://codepen.io/skunkbad/pen/EmBJMa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Regarding the showing on the wrong date:*

This is because of how you instantiate a date object and how it relates to timezones, your browser is likely resolving that to your timezone and you get a different value.

I am on GMT-3 and this is what happens for me for example:

```
$ new Date('2016-11-30')
- Tue Nov 29 2016 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)

$ new Date(2016, 11, 30)
- Fri Dec 30 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (BRT)
```

*Regarding not showing last data:*

The bar is plotted but it's not on visible location. It's possible to verify this on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4bjr17g/1/) (not sure why not on codepen), if you move your mouse to the very edge of the screen the label will appear.

This is a known issue and is being tracked here: [#2415](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2415)

If possible, I think that the easiest workaround would be to manually define a `max` property on your time scale

Comment: Thanks Raquel. I ended up fixing the problem by formatting the dates to include a timezone, per the moment.js docs, like "2017-06-05 08Z". You're solution is also helpful, and informative.